# Select records that are only associated with a record in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique

Not sure if the title explains this scenario in full, so I will be as descriptive as I can. I'm using a SQL Server database and have the following 4 tables:

**CUSTOMERS**:

```
CustomerID   CustomerName
--------------------------
100001       Mr J Bloggs
100002       Mr J Smith
```

**POLICIES**:

```
PolicyID  PolicyTypeID  CustomerID
-----------------------------------
100001    100001        100001
100002    100002        100001
100003    100003        100001
100004    100001        100002
100005    100002        100002
```

**POLICYTYPES**:

```
PolicyTypeID   PolTypeName   ProviderID
-----------------------------------------
100001         ISA           100001
100002         Pension       100001
100003         ISA           100002
```

**PROVIDERS**:

```
ProviderID    ProviderName
--------------------------
100001        ABC Ltd
100002        Bloggs Plc
```

This is obviously a stripped down version and the actual database contains a lot more records. What I am looking to do is return a list of clients who ONLY have products from a certain provider. So in the example above, if I want to return customers who have policies with ABC Ltd with this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    C.CustomerName, P.PolicyID, PT.PolTypeName, Providers.ProviderName
FROM 
    Customers C 
LEFT JOIN 
    Policies P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN 
    PolicyTypes PT ON P.PolicyTypeID = PT.PolicyTypeID
LEFT JOIN 
    Providers PR ON PR.ProviderID = PT.ProviderID
WHERE 
    PR.ProviderID = 100001
```

It will currently return both customers in the Customers table. But the customer Mr J Bloggs actually holds policies provided by Bloggs Plc as well. I don't want this. I only want to return the customers who hold ONLY policies from ABC Ltd, so the SQL I need should only return Mr J Smith.

Hope I've been clear, if not please let me know.

Many thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Side-note: you can use the _code_-button to format sql or sample data properly. You don't need `------` or `<br />` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty but readable:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, P.PolicyID, PT.PolTypeName, Providers.ProviderName
FROM Customers C LEFT JOIN Policies P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN PolicyTypes PT ON P.PolicyTypeID = PT.PolicyTypeID
LEFT JOIN Providers PR ON PR.ProviderID = PT.ProviderID
WHERE PR.ProviderID = 100001 AND C.CustomerName NOT IN (
    SELECT C.CustomerName
    FROM Customers C LEFT JOIN Policies P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN PolicyTypes PT ON P.PolicyTypeID = PT.PolicyTypeID
    LEFT JOIN Providers PR ON PR.ProviderID = PT.ProviderID
    WHERE PR.ProviderID <> 100001
)
```

Comment: Ha, we had the exact same idea!

Answer (score 1):

Tthe idea is that you additionally perform a NOT IN on customerid's that are linked to other providers:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, P.PolicyID, PT.PolTypeName, Providers.ProviderName
FROM Customers C LEFT JOIN Policies P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN PolicyTypes PT ON P.PolicyTypeID = PT.PolicyTypeID
LEFT JOIN Providers PR ON PR.ProviderID = PT.ProviderID
WHERE PR.ProviderID = 100001
--NEW PART
AND C.CustomerID NOT IN
(
    SELECT P.CustomerID
    FROM Policies P
    LEFT JOIN PolicyTypes PT ON P.PolicyTypeID = PT.PolicyTypeID
    LEFT JOIN Providers PR ON PR.ProviderID = PT.ProviderID
    WHERE PR.ProviderID <> 100001
)
```

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for all the suggestions. I have it working now. :)

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer. Any answer.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't appear to have that option (Im accessing this via my phone)

Comment: Are you using the App or the mobile site?

Comment: Im using the mobile site. Hold on, is it the tick? i.e do I make it green?

Comment: Seems you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, P.PolicyID, PT.PolTypeName, Providers.ProviderName 
    from Customers C inner join POLICIES P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
    inner join PT ON P.PolicyTypeID = PT.PolicyTypeID
    inner join Providers PR ON PR.ProviderID = PT.ProviderID
    where  PR.ProviderID = 100001 and c.CustomerID not in 
    (SELECT C.CustomerID from Customers C 
    inner join POLICIES P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID 
    inner join PT ON P.PolicyTypeID = PT.PolicyTypeID 
    inner join Providers PR ON PR.ProviderID = PT.ProviderID where  PR.ProviderID <> 100001)
```

Comment: You format this as code for a more elegant look. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for all the suggestions. I have it working now. :)